# OS Process Scheduling - What effect does a kernel system call have on a process scheduler?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduler, freertos, rtos

This question relates to system calls being executed when made by a running process, and how the scheduler is affected.

1. Let's say I have a process currently in the running state.
2. It decides it needs to do a system call (say, to access the disk) to the kernel API.
3. The process goes into blocked state. The scheduler chooses a pending process and lets it run.

My question is - if the other process is now running on the CPU, when/where is the system call getting executed? Or does scheduler wait until the system call finishes before choosing the pending process to run?

And a bonus question - whatever answer you give, is that the case for both general purpose operating systems and RTOS, or is it different for the later (since any RTOS scheduler is more sensitive to time and achieving deterministic performance).

Comment: 'when/where is the system call getting executed?' well, it is not.  It will not complete its execution and return until it is made ready/running again upon an I/O completion interrupt from the disk hardware.

Answer (score 3):

On modern x86-64, if the user mode process makes a system call asking for data on disk, the operating-system places the disk operation on the queue of operations of an AHCI or of an NVME PCI host controller. Both of these are PCI-Express devices which are DMA. The operating-system also holds all sorts of data structures itself to determine which operation belongs to which process and other things.

The operating-system asks the PCI device via memory mapped IO to do the operation and then puts the process on the blocked queue and waits for an MSI/MSI-X interrupt which acts similarly to an inter-processor interrupt in that it bypasses the IOAPIC to directly trigger an handler found in the IDT of a specific CPU core which can be specified by changing some settings using MMIO in the PCI registers of the PCI device (AHCI/NVME).

For more info, see my answer here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142525/data-transfer-between-cpu-ram-and-secondary-storage/142553#142553

Comment: Nice details :)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Follow up question: would this be the same flow on an RTOS? Is the system call capable of notifying the running process of length of the queue of operations, so that, if the queue is long and a RTOS timeout is expected to happen, the process making the system call could choose, for the sake of deterministic performance, not make the system call and do something alternative?

Comment: Edit: of course there is the option of having another system call to check the length of the queue before making the actual system call in question BUT the problem I am seeing is that if there is a context switch after the length check system call, it will lead to outdated information about the queue length once the process is made running again and ready to perform the actual disk I/O system call. In a general OS this might not be a problem but I am specifically thinking about RTOS and deterministic performance.

Comment: I'm not sure about RTOS. I mainly answered the first part of your question maybe someone can add about RTOS and etc.